# Helm upgrade command error for field kubernetes.io/ingress.class

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

Why do I get this error while running the helm upgrade command? I see my Ingress controller running fine

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.metadata): unknown field "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta, ValidationError(Ingress.metadata): unknown field "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta]
```

Below is my helm version

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.0", GitCommit:"e29ce2a54e96cd02ccfce88bee4f58bb6e2a28b6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.4"}
```

I do not get and server and client separately for helm version? Not sure if its because due to the latest helm version installed.

Any suggestion for my helm error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing the `annotation` scope:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: <whatever>
```

to debug such issues in the future, you can use `kubectl explain` which provides you with the optional fields:
try

```
kubectl explain ingress.metadata
```